# undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::CreateParams::CreateParams()'

Tags: c++, cmake, v8

I'm using Google V8 in my project.
But get an error when compiling it;

```
#include "js.h"

#include "v8.h"

Js::Js() {
    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
}
```

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/include)
link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/include)
```

make: undefined reference to `v8::Isolate::CreateParams::CreateParams()'

Comment: Note that `link_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/include)` only sets the folders for the linker to search when looking for a library but does not cause it to link to any specific library.

Comment: If I add v8_base to target_link_libraries I get  new error: cannot find -lv8_base: No such file or directory

Comment: I assume you added the wrong folder for the libraries. `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/v8/include` does not seem to be the place I would expect to have compiled library files.

Comment: Library files are typically in a subfolder called `lib`, not `include`.